# Rmarkdown: Continue Knitting if Errors in Chunk

Tags: r-markdown

I have an R Markdown file that I repurpose to analyze new samples.  Sometimes the analysis generates no significant results, and so when I try to plot the result an error is thrown.  I simply want to continue to Knit the PDF if such an error occurs.

I've tried  `{r error = TRUE}`, but the knitting still halts for some reason.  Is there another knitr option that would bypass the error?

```
{r Gene Ontology Enrichment, include = FALSE, error = TRUE}
enrichplot::barplot(ego.MF,
        font.size = 8,
        title="GO Enrichment - Molecular Function",
        showCategory=20)
```

```
Quitting from lines 441-478 (file.Rmd) 
Error in ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos] : 
  replacement has length zero
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the knitr options of the code chunk.  Evidently using `include = FALSE` with `error = TRUE` is not compatible.

Instead I switched to:
`{r Gene Ontology Enrichment, echo = FALSE, error = TRUE}`